# SQL cleaning function in python

Tags: python, django, function, django-views, sql-injection

So I have a message field on a form and I want to save the message into a database column named help_desk_message. I know that Django already tries to handle sql injection for you but I want to do a bit more. I want to clean my help_desk_message in my Views.py before saving it to the database by sending it to a function. so I would pass my message into a function `sql_message_cleaner(help_desk_message)`. I need help with the function that cleans out the sql injection. I tried writing it but it failed. I need the function in Python

Comment: Can you share the cleaning method and your form? Seems like this may be more appropriate as a field clean method on your form https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/forms/validation/#cleaning-a-specific-field-attribute

Comment: You don't need a special cleaner function.  Just use parameterized queries.